# ClientNamenodeProtocolProtos$AppendRequestProto overrides final method getUnknownFields.()Lcom/google/protobuf/UnknownFieldSet

Tags: java, maven, hadoop, apache-spark

I am trying to prepare a REST services deploying war in Tomcat 8 server where I need to use Spark. Rest service will create an RDD based on the HDFS file path. I am not able to find a suitable solution based on the below error messages:

> java.lang.VerifyError: class
>   org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.protocol.proto.ClientNamenodeProtocolProtos$AppendRequestProto
>   overrides final method
>   getUnknownFields.()Lcom/google/protobuf/UnknownFieldSet

Please suggest me a way to solve the issue. Find my pom.xml in below:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" 
 xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
 xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0
 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">

<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<groupId>org.devnet.transformation</groupId>
<artifactId>talendtransformation</artifactId>
<packaging>war</packaging>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<name>transformation</name>

<!-- <properties> <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding> 
    <jersey.version>2.12</jersey.version> </properties> -->

<build>
    <finalName>talendtransformation</finalName>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.5.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.8</source>
                <target>1.8</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
<repositories>
    <repository>
        <id>maven2-repository.java.net</id>
        <name>Java.net Repository for Maven</name>
        <url>http://download.java.net/maven/2/</url>
        <layout>default</layout>
    </repository>
</repositories>
<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
    <jersey2.version>2.19</jersey2.version>
    <jaxrs.version>2.0.1</jaxrs.version>
    <!-- <spark.version>1.5.0</spark.version>-->
    <spark.version>2.0.0</spark.version>    

    <akka.group>com.typesafe.akka</akka.group>
    <akka.version>2.3.11</akka.version>
    <scala.binary.version>2.10</scala.binary.version>

    <maven.version>3.3.3</maven.version>


</properties>

<dependencies>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/mysql/mysql-connector-java -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>mysql</groupId>
        <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        <version>5.1.38</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.thetransactioncompany/cors-filter -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.thetransactioncompany</groupId>
        <artifactId>cors-filter</artifactId>
        <version>1.3.2</version>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
                <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.17</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/commons-io/commons-io -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-io</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
        <version>2.5</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/commons-fileupload/commons-fileupload -->
    <!-- <dependency> <groupId>commons-fileupload</groupId> <artifactId>commons-fileupload</artifactId> 
        <version>1.3.2</version> </dependency> -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>jdk.tools</groupId>
        <artifactId>jdk.tools</artifactId>
        <version>${java.version}</version>
        <scope>system</scope>
        <systemPath>${JAVA_HOME}/lib/tools.jar</systemPath>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.hadoop</groupId>
        <artifactId>hadoop-mapreduce-client-core</artifactId>
        <version>2.6.0</version>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>com.google.protobuf</groupId>
                <artifactId>protobuf-java</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.hadoop</groupId>
        <artifactId>hadoop-common</artifactId>
        <version>2.6.0</version>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
                <artifactId>jersey-core</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
                <artifactId>jersey-json</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
                <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.mortbay.jetty</groupId>
                <artifactId>jetty</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.mortbay.jetty</groupId>
                <artifactId>jsp-api-2.1</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>com.google.code.findbugs</groupId>
                <artifactId>jsr305</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>com.google.protobuf</groupId>
                <artifactId>protobuf-java</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.hadoop</groupId>
        <artifactId>hadoop-client</artifactId>
        <version>2.6.0</version>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>com.google.protobuf</groupId>
                <artifactId>protobuf-java</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
        <artifactId>poi</artifactId>
        <version>3.7</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
        <artifactId>poi-ooxml</artifactId>
        <version>3.11</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.jcraft/jsch -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.jcraft</groupId>
        <artifactId>jsch</artifactId>
        <version>0.1.53</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Zip4j external jar for all Zipped operation -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>net.lingala.zip4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>zip4j</artifactId>
        <version>1.3.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.google.guava/guava -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
        <artifactId>guava</artifactId>
        <version>11.0.2</version>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>  <!-- declare the exclusion here -->
                <groupId>com.google.code.findbugs</groupId>
                <artifactId>jsr305</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
        <version>3.4</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- <dependency> <groupId>org.apache.tomcat</groupId> <artifactId>tomcat-coyote</artifactId> 
        <version>7.0.27</version> </dependency> <dependency> <groupId>org.apache.tomcat</groupId> 
        <artifactId>tomcat-coyote</artifactId> <version>7.0.14</version> </dependency> -->

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.jolbox/bonecp -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.jolbox</groupId>
        <artifactId>bonecp</artifactId>
        <version>0.8.0.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.json</groupId>
        <artifactId>json</artifactId>
        <version>20160810</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>asm</groupId>
        <artifactId>asm</artifactId>
        <version>3.3.1</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.ws.rs</groupId>
        <artifactId>jsr311-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.ws.rs/javax.ws.rs-api -->
    <!-- <dependency> <groupId>javax.ws.rs</groupId> <artifactId>javax.ws.rs-api</artifactId> 
        <version>2.1-m05</version> </dependency> -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.bundles</groupId>
        <artifactId>jaxrs-ri</artifactId>
        <version>${jersey2.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.media</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-media-json-processing</artifactId>
        <version>${jersey2.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.media</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-media-json-jackson</artifactId>
        <version>${jersey2.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.media</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-media-multipart</artifactId>
        <version>${jersey2.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.media</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-media-moxy</artifactId>
        <version>${jersey2.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-server</artifactId>
        <version>${jersey2.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.containers</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-container-servlet</artifactId>
        <version>${jersey2.version}</version>
        <!-- <exclusions> <exclusion> <groupId>javax.ws.rs</groupId> <artifactId>javax.ws.rs-api</artifactId> 
            </exclusion> </exclusions> -->
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-client</artifactId>
        <version>${jersey2.version}</version>
        <!-- <exclusions> <exclusion> <groupId>javax.ws.rs</groupId> <artifactId>javax.ws.rs-api</artifactId> 
            </exclusion> </exclusions> -->
    </dependency>
    <!-- <dependency> <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId> <artifactId>jersey-bundle</artifactId> 
        <version>1.19</version> <exclusions> <exclusion> <groupId>javax.ws.rs</groupId> 
        <artifactId>jsr311-api</artifactId> </exclusion> </exclusions> </dependency> 
        <dependency> <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId> <artifactId>jersey-json</artifactId> 
        <version>1.19.1</version> <exclusions> <exclusion> <groupId>javax.ws.rs</groupId> 
        <artifactId>jsr311-api</artifactId> </exclusion> </exclusions> </dependency> 
        <dependency> <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId> <artifactId>jersey-server</artifactId> 
        <version>1.19</version> </dependency> <dependency> <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId> 
        <artifactId>jersey-core</artifactId> <version>1.19</version> <exclusions> 
        <exclusion> <groupId>javax.ws.rs</groupId> <artifactId>jsr311-api</artifactId> 
        </exclusion> </exclusions> </dependency> <dependency> <groupId>com.sun.jersey.contribs</groupId> 
        <artifactId>jersey-multipart</artifactId> <version>1.19</version> </dependency> 
        <dependency> <groupId>javax.ws.rs</groupId> <artifactId>javax.ws.rs-api</artifactId> 
        <version>2.0-m12</version> </dependency> -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.1</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>taglibs</groupId>
        <artifactId>standard</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.httpcomponents/httpclient -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
        <artifactId>httpclient</artifactId>
        <version>4.5.3</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- For Json Formation with one element -->
    <!-- <dependency> <groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId> <artifactId>jackson-jaxrs</artifactId> 
        <version>1.9.13</version> </dependency> <dependency> <groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId> 
        <artifactId>jackson-xc</artifactId> <version>1.9.13</version> </dependency> -->

    <!-- Jars for Spark Operation -->
    <!-- <dependency> <groupId>com.sparkjava</groupId> <artifactId>spark-core</artifactId> 
        <version>2.5.5</version> <exclusions> <exclusion> <groupId>com.google.code.findbugs</groupId> 
        <artifactId>jsr305</artifactId> </exclusion> </exclusions> </dependency> -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
        <artifactId>spark-core_2.10</artifactId>
        <version>${spark.version}</version>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>com.typesafe.akka</groupId>
                <artifactId>akka-slf4j_2.10</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>com.typesafe.akka</groupId>
                <artifactId>akka-remote_2.10</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>com.google.code.findbugs</groupId>
                <artifactId>jsr305</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.apache.mesos</groupId>
                <artifactId>mesos</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <!--<exclusion> <artifactId>jackson-module-scala_2.10</artifactId> <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.module</groupId> 
                </exclusion> -->
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
        <artifactId>spark-sql_2.10</artifactId>
        <version>${spark.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- <dependency> <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId> <artifactId>spark-streaming_2.11</artifactId> 
        <version>2.0.0</version> </dependency> <dependency> <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId> 
        <artifactId>spark-mllib_2.11</artifactId> <version>2.0.0</version> </dependency> -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.hive</groupId>
        <artifactId>hive-exec</artifactId>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>  <!-- declare the exclusion here -->
                <groupId>com.google.protobuf</groupId>
                <artifactId>protobuf-java</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
        <version>0.11.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.hive/hive-jdbc -->
    <!-- <dependency> <groupId>org.apache.hive</groupId> <artifactId>hive-jdbc</artifactId> 
        <version>2.1.1</version> </dependency> -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.hive</groupId>
        <artifactId>hive-jdbc</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.0</version>
        <classifier>standalone</classifier>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>com.google.code.findbugs</groupId>
                <artifactId>jsr305</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>com.google.protobuf</groupId>
                <artifactId>protobuf-java</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.hive/hive-service -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.hive</groupId>
        <artifactId>hive-service</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.1</version>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>  <!-- declare the exclusion here -->
                <groupId>io.netty</groupId>
                <artifactId>netty-all</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>  <!-- declare the exclusion here -->
                <groupId>com.google.code.findbugs</groupId>
                <artifactId>jsr305</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>  <!-- declare the exclusion here -->
                <groupId>com.google.protobuf</groupId>
                <artifactId>protobuf-java</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <!-- When error messages occure like : No FileSystem for HDFS -->
    <!-- <dependency> <groupId>org.apache.hadoop</groupId> <artifactId>hadoop-hdfs</artifactId> 
        <version>2.6.0</version> </dependency> -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.jdo</groupId>
        <artifactId>jdo2-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.3-eb</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- new add -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.ws.rs</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.ws.rs-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-simple</artifactId>
        <version>1.7.7</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- jackson-fasterxml -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-core</artifactId>
        <version>2.6.5</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
        <version>2.6.5</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-annotations</artifactId>
        <version>2.6.5</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.protobuf</groupId>
        <artifactId>protobuf-java</artifactId>
        <version>2.6.0</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- <dependency> <groupId>com.typesafe</groupId> <artifactId>config</artifactId> 
        <version>1.2.0</version> </dependency> <dependency> <groupId>org.spark-project.akka</groupId> 
        <artifactId>akka-remote_2.10</artifactId> <version>2.3.11-shaded-protobuf</version> 
        </dependency> <dependency> <groupId>org.spark-project.akka</groupId> <artifactId>akka-slf4j_2.10</artifactId> 
        <version>2.3.11-shaded-protobuf</version> </dependency> <dependency> <groupId>com.typesafe.akka</groupId> 
        <artifactId>akka-actor_2.10</artifactId> <version>2.3.11</version> </dependency> 
        <dependency> <groupId>com.google.protobuf</groupId> <artifactId>protobuf-java</artifactId> 
        <version>${protobuf.version}</version> <scope>${hadoop.deps.scope}</scope> 
        </dependency> -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>${akka.group}</groupId>
        <artifactId>akka-actor_${scala.binary.version}</artifactId>
        <version>${akka.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>${akka.group}</groupId>
        <artifactId>akka-remote_${scala.binary.version}</artifactId>
        <version>${akka.version}</version>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>com.google.protobuf</groupId>
                <artifactId>protobuf-java</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>${akka.group}</groupId>
        <artifactId>akka-slf4j_${scala.binary.version}</artifactId>
        <version>${akka.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>${akka.group}</groupId>
        <artifactId>akka-testkit_${scala.binary.version}</artifactId>
        <version>${akka.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- <dependency> <groupId>${akka.group}</groupId> <artifactId>akka-zeromq_${scala.binary.version}</artifactId> 
        <version>${akka.version}</version> <exclusions> <exclusion> <groupId>${akka.group}</groupId> 
        <artifactId>akka-actor_${scala.binary.version}</artifactId> </exclusion> 
        </exclusions> </dependency> -->
</dependencies>
```